# How to remove account and github permission in onlinetool.io

Tags: github, user-accounts, gist

I'm not sure if this is the right site to ask this question. Please direct me to the correct one and I'll repost.

I came across with a site where there is a link for codeeval.dev. I click the link so i can create account in CodeEval. I successfully created an account and it asked for permission on accessing my private info in github account. I gave it permission. After all the creation of account, I noticed the link box and it is not codeeval.dev but onlinetool.io/gisteditor/. I regreted what I did and want to delete the account as well as remove the permission to access my github.

My questions are:
-**how to remove account in onlinetool.io?**
-**how to remove the permission to access my github?**

I looked in onlinetool.io and there is no option for removing account.
I looked in github and I can't find managing permissions for external account like in onlinetool.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to visit either https://github.com/settings/applications or https://github.com/settings/apps/authorizations to remove the permission to access your github. For removing your account in onlinetool.io, I guess you could try to file a Data Erasure request(GDPR and CCPR) by sending an email to the site, and they have to legally respond within 30 days.